# Is there a way to define output folder per file with Dotfuscator?

Tags: dotfuscator

This is a part of my Obfuscation XML file:

```
 <inputassembly refid="1d9224f1-30bd-49dc-8e3a-30753XY2ed4d">
    <option>honoroas</option>
    <option>stripoa</option>
    <option>library</option>
    <option>transformxaml</option>
    <file dir="${buildfolder}" name="My.precious.dll" />
  </inputassembly>
```

Is there a way to also define an output folder?
Right now, all dlls go to the same output folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a solution in Dotfuscator Community, except to wrap the build in your own script that moves the files around. In Dotfuscator Professional, you can configure a [post-build event](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/interfaces_config_editor_overview.html#pctoc-build-events) for each module, and that event could copy or move it. There are some [additional properties](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/protection_build_and_debug.html#pctoc-build-events) that are defined for post-build events, that might be useful.

Full disclosure: I work for PreEmptive Solutions, who makes Dotfuscator.